# How to change tab order on ul wrapping in different divs?

Tags: html, tabindex

I have the html structure like this

```
<div class="first_div">
  <ul class="menu">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="second_div">
  <ul class="menu">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

By default the tab first goes to the `first div menu` and then the `second div menu`.

But I want to change its order. I want the tab should go first to the second div menu and then the first div menu.

I have tried by giving the `tabindex="1"` to the second div and `tabindex="2"` to the first div but its not working.

Note: I can't change the html structure.

Comment: when you say "the tab first goes to" does the tab mean you are pressing the tab key? Or is this some sort of jQuery tabs?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Here is a jsfiddle approximating what I think you were trying to do. It is working as you wanted it to as far as I understand. Can you update your question with something like this and describe what is happening vs what is expected?
https://jsfiddle.net/ccuo99yn/

Comment: yes I mean the tab key

Comment: Can you use something like jsfiddle to explain the issue? The one I posted above seems to work as far as I can see. Are you dynamically adding the tabindex with javascript?

Comment: yes I'm adding the tabindex through javascript

Comment: any help for this?

Answer (score 0):

[`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) seems to do the trick. Even after dynamically adding and re-setting the `tabindex` is working.

Here is the snippet:

```js
var cnt = 2;

function btnAdd_Clicked() {
  cnt++;

  document.body.innerHTML += '<div class="div_' + cnt + '"><ul class="menu" tabindex="' + cnt + '">...' + (cnt) + '...</ul></div';
}

function btnReoder_Clicked() {
  var uls = document.querySelectorAll("body>div>ul");
  for (var i = uls.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    uls[i].setAttribute('tabindex', (cnt - i));
  }
}
```

```css
body>div {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 5px;
}
body>div>ul {
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <button onclick="btnAdd_Clicked()">Add</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button onclick="btnReoder_Clicked()">Reverse tab</button>
  </p>
  <div class="first_div">
    <ul class="menu" tabindex="2">
      ....First..
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="second_div">
    <ul class="menu" tabindex="1">
      ...Second...
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```